# Where is the AutoLayout template in Instruments?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, instruments

[Apple recommends using the Auto Layout template in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW14) to help debug Auto Layout issues. I can't find it among the templates in Xcode 5.0.2 (I see "Blank", "Allocations", "Leaks", but no Auto Layout).

Where is this template located?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "blank" template. Then, from the library, select and drag the "Cocoa Layout" template

[image: Blank template]

[image: Cocoa Layout]

Comment: From what I can tell, this Instrument seems to be OSX-only -- can some one else confirm?

Comment: It does looks like it.

Comment: ? I used it just few days ago on iOS.

Comment: For me, this worked on the simulator, but reported a 'This device does not support this instrument' error when attempting to run it on iPhone 4s hardware.

Comment: Seems to be OS X only